# Is anyway to see inline errors in Python CANOPY?

Tags: python, matlab, editor, canopy

As you know in `MATLAB editor` we have a feature to show inline errors :

[image]

Is anyway to show inline messages in `Python CANOPY`? It is hard to run the code and check `Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment` to find basic errors in code. `CANOPY editor` only show the position of error without any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the user guide: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#syntax-checking-with-pyflakes

> A small ! icon in the status bar shows you the total number of errors and warnings in the current file. If you click this icon, then you will toggle the error description at the right of each affected line.